# iText(sharp) side margins width

Tags: c#, itext, margin

It looks like I can't set left margin to be less then 42pt width. I am setting it to 0f but it always ends as 42pt. If I set margin to any number greater then 0 it just adds it to initial margin of 42pt. I am setting margin of document object:

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle docRect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(pageWidth, pageHeight);
DC = new Document(docRect);
DC.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Page width and height are 6x9 in.

And I end with:

42pt margin|CONTENT CONTENT

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: How are you adding your content to the Document?  That can have an impact on where it is placed by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am using PdfPTable and the problem was default PdfPTable horizontal alignment which is CENTER. As soon as I set alignmentof table to left problem went away.

```
PdfPTable bTable = new PdfPTable(2);
bTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
```

Thanks,
Velja

Comment: how to set margin.i want my pdf table in fix position

Answer (score 10):

Well, I think that the problem is different. By default, `PdfPTable.LockedWidth` property is set to false, and `PdfPTable.WidthPercentage` is equal to `80f`. As long as default table alignment is `Center` you get the impression that your margins are not honoured... but they are! You sipmly need to set `PdfPTable.WidthPercentage = 100f`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may have to do with how you are adding the content to your document.  If you are using a Table (instead of a PdfPTable), even if you have a left margin of 0, the table will still be placed indented from the left margin by default.

The default spacing works out to be about 10% of the width of the printable page area.  So the left edge of the Table would be placed at `( 0.10 * (pageWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin))`.

10% of 6 inches (at 72 pts per inch) is equal to 43.2 pts, pretty close to the 42 pts you are getting.